# How to run select query of post with category and tags for API?

Tags: categories, mysql, tags, api

I want to fetch multiple posts with categories and tags.
Actually, I'm creating an API for my Wordpress site, full code is like this :

```
 $mysql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT p.post_title,
       p.ID,
       p.post_content,
       p.post_date,
       p.post_name as url,
       t.name as category_name
FROM wp_posts p,
     wp_terms t,
     wp_term_relationships r,
     wp_term_taxonomy tt
WHERE p.post_status='publish' AND
      tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND
      p.id=r.object_id AND
      r.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id AND
      tt.term_id = t.term_id order by p.post_date desc limit ".(int)($pageNumber*$pageSize).",".(int)$pageSize."") or die ("error".mysqli_error($con));
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($mysql);
```

The MySQLi connection works. But when I run this code, I only get a blank page. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can do this with `WP_Query`, there's no need for a handwritten SQL query. You also don't need an `api2.php` file, jsut use a REST API endpoint. You've also probably got a PHP Fatal error, hence the white page, turn on error logging and check the PHP error log to see the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress already has an API you can extend, and a class for querying posts!

For example:

```
// when the rest_api_init action/event happens
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  // register a new endpoint
  register_rest_route( 'mohnish/v1', '/posts/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'mohnish_awesome_func', // that calls this function
  ) );
} );

// this is whats called when something hits the endpoint
function mohnish_awesome_func( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // grab the parameters
    $category = $request->get_param( 'category' );
    $tag = $request->get_param( 'tag' );

    // run the query to fetch the data
    $q = new WP_Query( [
        'category_name' => $category,
        'tag' => $tag,
        // etc...
    ]);
    $results = []; // an empty array to hold our results

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        while( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();
            // add a new result to the list
            $results[] = [
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                // etc...
            ];
        }
    }

    return $results; // the REST API will automagically convert this to json
}
```

This would let you write URLs such as:

https://example.com/wp-json/mohnish/v1/posts/?category=foo&tag=bar

And get a JSON data structure back with information.

Luckily, Core already has a posts endpoint that does a lot of what you want to do at `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, here's an example with a live site:

`curl http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

You can see [a full schema of what it returns here with examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) on deleting posting and grabbing individual posts here, as well as [a handbook detailing how to use all its features](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and extend it

Comment: can you tell me where i add this code exactly .. i need to customize my api according to my client where next page url, only 20 post fetch on one time  etc. function included .

Comment: It can go anywhere that a hook would normally go ( and you should be using plugins to build functionality, not themes, and definitely not standalone files in the root, think of the security! ). Also keep in mind it's an example, a starting point, adding in the final bits like how many posts to fetch in the query should be trivial